# Is it sufficient to apply ssl to the proxy but not the services being proxied?

Tags: security, ssl, proxy, ssl-certificate

I was wondering if enabling SSL on the proxy is enough but not on the services being proxied. Would there be issues from the outside (on client side) when comms are supposed to be https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the proxied service is only accessible by the proxy itself there shouldn't be any security issue. All communications between the client and the proxy are secure and the proxy is the only one talking to the service without encryption however if the proxied service is not accessible to the world you are ok.